# Summary will not update on rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

[image]I have pushed a new version of a gem to rubygems. The new version number is shown on the rubygems website, but the summary has not changed. I have checked the last commit prior to pushing the gem, and the gemspec includes the new summary and a new description.  Also, if I look at the main title of the gem on the website (i.e at the very top of the page), the version being displayed is the previous version. I am using `gem push 1.0.1-<gemname>` to publish the gem.

I have attached a screenshot, if you look at the main title, you can see it is at .002 yet the version list below shows the most recent is 1.0.2, so something is not updating properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After at least a week of the problem appearing, it fixed itself.  One suggestion was that it was caused by not clearing my browser cache. If you do see a problem like this, and clearing the browser cache does not fix it, please reopen [this issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/issues/1380#issuecomment-238459098).